# Does the dating of the formation of the world take into account the effect of space-time curvature?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, space-expansion

For example, when we calculated that the age of the universe is about 13.8 billion years, did we take into account the difference between the flow of time back at the early universe, where mass was way more concentrated, and the flow right now?

Comment: We use the proper time τ instead of the coordinate time t, so we don't need to. Since the uncertainty bars on the earth's age are miles high as well no one cares about such [peanuts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JWncwRTMKkI&t=198s), even if he were to use t instead of τ.

Answer (score 0):

The "age of the Universe" in cosmology answers the following question: if a stopwatch somehow formed a fraction of a second after the Big Bang and kept ticking all throughout the history of the Universe, what would the reading be on the stopwatch when we found it today?

You don't need to be so careful about defining time when dealing with timescales over which the Universe's size did not change very much. The age of the Earth is big enough that cosmological effects are not completely negligible, but are still small.